# Ubuntu wifi connected but not working correctly

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, gnome, drivers, gdm3

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my old Lenovo G50-80. I've been having issues with getting the wifi to work from the start. During install I gave it a network cable and then after the install I couldn't get the wifi working at first so I configured it manually somehow in Unity (something like adding a record about a "Host" with AP name and password in a config file). At last it was working, so I started polishing the look, and decided to go with gnome instead. Now the wifi still works on login and it automatically connects to my AP but as soon as I open my VPN client, connect and then later disconnect, it will not work again for some reason.

At any point in time, when I try to change the gnome UI wifi settings, it's searching and never seems to find any APs, despite me already being connected to my own AP when looking at it.

Is gnome not recognizing my wifi drivers?

Otherwise, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, iptables. This was nothing driver related as I suggested might have been the problem in my question.

I did `iptables -L` and quickly saw that my VPN rules were still in place. A quick `iptables -F` did the trick. Kinda weird that the VPN client wouldn't replace those rules once exited.

Comment: That is a pain but it happens a lot. I use OpenVPN and when it exits "gracefully" there is no problem, but if it crashes, there are often "pieces" like routes and dns servers left behind